# how does gcd program calculate the result correctly

Tags: c++

```
    class GcdCal {
public:
    int gcd(int a,int b){
        if(a<b){
            int temp =a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        int r = a%b;
        if(r == 0){
            cout<< b;
        }else{
            //cout<< b<< "   "<< r<<" *** ";
            gcd(b,r);
        }
        return b;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a= 44;
    int b= 16;
    GcdCal numberTest;
    int result = numberTest.gcd(a,b);
    cout<< result;
    cout<<"gcd is "<<result;
}
```

I am a new man of C++, I just wanted to calculate the gcd with C++, but the program output the wrong result, instead 4 but 16,sometimes even 0, I don't know where is wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Do you really need this function to be a part of a class? You don't have to implement _everyhing_ as a class in C++.

Comment: Are you saying this same code, unchanged, does not always produce the same output when run?

Comment: This doesn't return the recursive calls, so it almost certainly doesn't word correctly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting a bit confused from trying to both return a result and print it.
This function should return a value, and you need to remember to return the result of the recursion, otherwise it disappears into the great bitbucket in the sky.

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (a < b){
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
    int r = a % b;
    if (r == 0) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return gcd(b, r);
    }
}
```

or, shorter:

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (a < b){
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
    int r = a % b;
    return r == 0 ? b : gcd(b, r);
}
```

(As a side note, there's no point in putting that function in a class.)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion implemented incorrectly. It returns result of the first iteration, but should return the last. Replace

```
if(r == 0){
    cout<< b;
}else{
    //cout<< b<< "   "<< r<<" *** ";
    gcd(b,r);
}
return b;
```

with

```
if(r == 0){
    cout<< b;
    return b;
}else{
    //cout<< b<< "   "<< r<<" *** ";
    return gcd(b,r);
}
```